# Drawing number from set and throw coin

Tags: probability

We draw number $k$ from set $\left\{ 1,2,3,..., n-1,n \right\}$ and then we throw $k$-times a coin. Let $E_n$ will be expected value of numbers heads (obverse). Is it true that:

1. $E_{11} > 3$
2. $E_8>2$
3. $E_{14} > 4$
4. $E_3 > 1$

I tried compute it expected value for some $n$. I think that

$$E_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} {k \choose 1} + 2\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{2^k} {k \choose 2} + 3\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{1}{2^k} {k \choose 3} + ... + (n-1) \sum_{k=n-1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} {k \choose n-1} + \sum_{k=n}^n \frac{1}{2^k} {k \choose n} = \sum_{i=1}^n i \sum_{k=i}^n \frac{1}{2^k} {k \choose i}$$

Does it work? If yes, how can I estimate for example $E_{11}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of coin tosses, $H$ be the number of heads and $T$ be the number of tails. Clearly $H$ and $T$ have the same distribution, so $E(H)=E(T)$. But since $X=H+T$, we also have $E(X)=E(H)+E(T)=2E(H)$, so $E(H)=\frac{E(X)}{2}$. Since $E(X)=\frac{n+1}{2}$, $E(H)=\frac{n+1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

If "drawing $k$ from a finite set" means "drawing $k$ uniformly randomly from this set", a simpler route might be to first compute the expected value of the number of heads knowing $k$, which is obviously $\frac12k$, and then the expectation of *that*. If $k$ is uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, its mean value is $\frac12(n+1)$, hence
$$
E_n=\frac{n+1}4.
$$
The trick used above is often called the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).